# SQL Server 2016 - WHILE loop inside IF statement still occurring when condition has not been met

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, while-loop, nested, duplicates

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201111/sql-server-2016-inserting-remaining-rows-into-a-table-leading-to-duplicates-of), I have used the below code to insert 3 rows of data into table PeopleStatusCodes.

```
--declare temporary tables
DECLARE @peopleStatus TABLE (peopleStatusID INT)
DECLARE @data TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR (100), LastName VARCHAR (100), Codename VARCHAR (100))

--insert data into @data
INSERT INTO @data(
    [FirstName]
   ,[LastName]
   ,[Codename]
)
VALUES(
    'John'
   ,'Smith'
   ,'02 - Code2'
)

--check if entry exists inside PeopleStatus and insert into @peopleStatus based on that
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [ps].[PersonCode] FROM PeopleStatus [ps], People [p], @data [d]
WHERE [ps].[PersonCode] = [p].[PersonCode]
AND [p].[FirstName] = [d].[FirstName]
AND [p].[LastName] = [d].[LastName])
    INSERT INTO PeopleStatus (
           [PersonCode]
          ,[Status]
    )
    OUTPUT inserted.[ID]
    INTO @peopleStatus
    SELECT
           [p].[PersonCode]
          ,1
    FROM [People] [p], @data [d]
    WHERE [p].[FirstName] = [d].[FirstName]
      AND [p].[LastName] = [d].[LastName]
ELSE INSERT INTO @peopleStatus (peopleStatusID)
SELECT [ps].[ID]
FROM PeopleStatus [ps], People [p], @data [d]
WHERE [ps].[PersonCode] = [p].[PersonCode]
AND [p].[FirstName] = [d].[FirstName]
AND [p].[LastName] = [d].[LastName]

--insert into PeopleStatusCodes a row of data for each Code in the Codes table with Result defaulting to 0
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [psc].ID
FROM PeopleStatusCodes [psc], @peopleStatus [temp]
WHERE [psc].PeopleStatusID = [temp].peopleStatusID)

    DECLARE @IDColumn VARCHAR (10)
    SELECT @IDColumn = MIN(c.ID)
    FROM Codes [c]
    WHILE @IDColumn IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[PeopleStatusCodes] (
             [PeopleStatusID]
            ,[CodeID]
            ,[Result]
        )
        SELECT
             [temp].[peopleStatusID]
            ,@IDColumn
            ,0
        FROM @peopleStatus [temp]

        SELECT @IDColumn = MIN(c.ID)
        FROM Codes [c]
        WHERE c.ID > @IDColumn
    END

--Checks if the data matching row has not had Result changed to 1 already, and if so, update that row.
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [psc].ID
FROM PeopleStatusCodes [psc], @peopleStatus [temp]
WHERE [psc].PeopleStatusID = [temp].peopleStatusID 
AND [psc].CodeID = (SELECT [c].ID FROM Codes [c], @data [d] WHERE [c].CodeNumber + ' - ' + [c].Name = [d].[Codename])
AND [psc].Result = 1)
UPDATE [dbo].[PeopleStatusCodes] SET Result = 1 WHERE CodeID = (SELECT [c].ID FROM Codes [c], @data [d] WHERE [c].CodeNumber + ' - ' + [c].Name = [d].[Codename])
```

The results are as follows and are what I want:

```
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
| ID | PeopleStatusID | CodeID | Result |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
|  1 |              1 |      1 |      0 |
|  2 |              1 |      2 |      1 |
|  3 |              1 |      3 |      0 |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
```

I then decide to insert a second set of data: I want person John Smith to also have Code3 with a successful result. So I run the code again, and just change the the `[Codename]` column of `@data` to instead have the value '03 - Code3'. The result I want is:

```
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
| ID | PeopleStatusID | CodeID | Result |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
|  1 |              1 |      1 |      0 |
|  2 |              1 |      2 |      1 |
|  3 |              1 |      3 |      1 |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
```

In the above scenario, only one row has been updated. However, when I run the code, instead I get a new set of rows per Code:

```
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
| ID | PeopleStatusID | CodeID | Result |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
|  1 |              1 |      1 |      0 |
|  2 |              1 |      2 |      1 |
|  3 |              1 |      3 |      0 |
|  4 |              1 |      1 |      0 |
|  5 |              1 |      2 |      0 |
|  6 |              1 |      3 |      1 |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+
```

It seems like the IF statement's condition `SELECT [psc].ID
FROM PeopleStatusCodes [psc], @peopleStatus [temp]
WHERE [psc].PeopleStatusID = [temp].peopleStatusID` is being ignored, but I'm not sure why. I tried putting brackets around the WHILE statement so it only runs if the above condition is met, but SQL Server considers the brackets as syntactically wrong.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [psc].ID` needs begin - end.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it'd be safer to also apply it to the earlier IF ELSE statement, although that one seems to be working just fine - it doesn't insert a second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use BEGIN ... END for IF condition

IF something = something
BEGIN

...

END

Otherwise IF is applicable only to the very first statement after IF condition

Comment: That makes sense. I'm guessing this also applies to ELSE statements, since trying to use ELSE for the second IF statement shows up as being syntactically incorrect (since the first statement already has ELSE).